# How can we ensure the immutability of a ArrayList defined in a Immutable Object?

Tags: java, immutability

If I am defining an ArrayList in Java which is private, final and only with getters. Still user can get the ArrayList and modify the ArrayList by adding or removing the elements from it. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an unmodifiable List out of your list. [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) class have a utility method for this.

```
 List<String> unModifiableList=Collections.unmodifiableList(
                                        oldList);
```

Once you prepare the list inside your actual object, you can freeze it.

Answer (score 0):

[Unmodifiable List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) is the approach you have to take. But there's a limitation since this unmodifiable class is taking a usual List and it is still modifiable.

```
final List<String> modifiable = new ArrayList<>();
modifiable.add("Java");
modifiable.add("is");

final List<String> unmodifiable = Collections.unmodifiableList(modifiable);
System.out.print("Before modification: " + unmodifiable);

modifiable.add("the");
modifiable.add("best");

System.out.print("After modification: " + unmodifiable);
```

In the above code segment output is unexpected as below.

> Before modification: [Java, is]
>   After modification: [Java, is, the, best]

Read [this article](http://www.javacreed.com/modifying-an-unmodifiable-list/) to understand the **pitfalls of unmodifiableList** and the solutions for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return new instance of List in your getter method with your list as constructor argument.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just return a copy of the list and let clients play with it if they want. Note that making the objects inside the list also immutable is a completely different challenge...